# R Studio no me devuelve los mismos resultados que SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: r

Estoy ejecutando esta simple consulta

```
select count(*) altas
from ohem 
where U_Activo='Sí'
```

Que en SQl Server Management Studio me devuelve el valor 112

pero cuando la meto en una funcion de R

```
EmpleadosAlta2<-function(){
 return(
  dbGetQuery(con,"
   select count(*) altas
   from ohem 
   where U_Activo='Sí'"
))  
}
```

y luego la llamo tal que asi

```
> EmpleadosAlta2()
altas
1     0
```

tengo la conexion y las librerias perfectamente instaladas

```
>con
<OdbcConnection> dbo@HP-KINTELA\SQLEXPRESS
Database: FULCRUM
Microsoft SQL Server Version: 11.00.2100
```

De hecho si ejecuto esta otra consulta similar soilo cambiando el vaor del filtro todo va bien

```
EmpleadosBaja2<-function(){
 return(
  dbGetQuery(con,"
   select count(*) bajas
   from ohem 
   where U_Activo='No'"
))  
}
```

El resultado es el mismo que obtengo en SQl Server Management Studio

```
EmpleadosBaja2()
bajas
1   455
```

Con lo cual asumo que el problema está en el acento del Sí pero no se como evitarlo

Si ejecuto esto

```
Plantilla<-function(year){
 return(
  dbGetQuery(con,"
   select U_Activo, count(*) altas from ohem group by U_Activo"
))  
}
```

Obtengo esto

```
Plantilla()
  U_Activo altas
1       No   455
2       Sí   112
```

Y si la query con el filtro u_activo='Sí' la meto en un procedimiento almacenado y luego llamos desde R a ese procedimiento todo va bien pero si quieres hacer inline SQL no encuentro la solucion

Un saludo

Comment: Prueba correr este query mediante R `select U_Activo, count(*) altas from ohem group by U_Activo`, y agrega la salida a tu pregunta.

Comment: Tiene una pinta de ser problema con la tilde...

Comment: Pareciera ser algún tema de incompatibilidad de codificación, el `Sí` acentuado de tu consulta termina siendo una cadena distinta en el servidor, es muy raro. Revisa que tu script este codificado en UTF-8. Puedes también probar variar la codificación de tu consulta, por ejemplo `Encoding(consulta) <- 'UTF-8'` y probar con otras, antes de pasarselo al `dbGetQuery`.